# How to add number to a start value number every few seconds using JS and HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Im building a browser real time text based game. Im new to js and all that right. I have a feature where the player requires resources to lets say upgrade a building or build a certain unit.
Lets say for my question, I have a metal mine with 100 metal in it and I want to have it add 10 metal ever 3 seconds to the already existing 100 metal, and then stops adding 10 metal when it reaches a set cap of lets say 500 metal.
I know I have to use JS to get that right but I dont know how to code it and implement it onto the client side.

I dont have any JS examples but basically have this html code.

```
<h3><span class="color-1">Metal: 100</span> | <span class="color-2">Gas: 100</span> | <span class="color-3">Oil: 100</span> | <span class="color-4">Power: 470</span></h3>
```

Okay and then I want to add a function that when the player builds something that costs lets say 50 metal, I want that function to subtract 50 from its total already and then start adding 10 metal every 3 seconds.

Comment: If you don't have any JS code yet, I would strongly suggest that you try to write some. Once you get stuck you can update your question to be more specific about the problem.

Comment: Try something with basic JS and comes back when you are blocked with an error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a small example of your mine using a `setInterval`:

```js
const mEl = document.getElementById('metal')
const user = {
  resources: {
    metal: 100
  },
  caps: {
    // ...
    metal: 500
  }
}

const modifyMetal = m => {
  if (!typeof newMetal === 'number') {
    throw new Error('Invalid paramater type passed to modifyMetal')
  }
  if (user.resources.metal + m < 0 || user.resources.metal === user.caps.metal) {
    return null
  }
  if (user.resources.metal + m >= user.caps.metal) {
    return mEl.textContent = user.resources.metal = user.caps.metal
  }

  return mEl.textContent = user.resources.metal += m
}

const mine = setInterval(() => {
  modifyMetal(3)
}, 300)

const build = () => {
  modifyMetal(-50) ? console.log('Build Action') : console.log('Not enough metal')
}
```

```html
<span id="metal">100</span> metal
<br>
<button onclick="build()">Build</button>
```

Comment: If my answer isn't good enough, let me know how I can improve it :)

Comment: I am __not__ the downvoter, but you should take into account that op wants to stop adding stuff when a certain amount has been reached. I don't think a satisfying answer can be reached since problem is way too opened but your answer does not seem to be since you never stop the interval!

Comment: Looks like, this is the answer. But why down vote !?

Comment: @user753642 That's true, but I haven't finnished writing my answer yet, I'll add that in now.

Comment: Thank you its just that what I need and a way to get it to stop adding onto let metal = 100 when it reaches 500. Also do I just open a .js file and put the code in there and link it to the html form for it to run or are there other steps involved

Comment: Sorry If I downvoted you, Im new to stackoverflow so not sure how the features works. your answer is 100% for me bud. sorry again

Comment: @Lex-Digitals You didn't, don't worry :) I've updated my answer now, it should work exactly how you asked 

Comment: Thank you Kobe, its exactly what I need.

Comment: @Lex-Digitals No problem. If you need anymore help or don't understand something that I've written, feel free to ask :)

Comment: user753642 -  I know, when ever I get stuck I ask for code. As I build the game I learn on the way. Ill post what I have on solo learn then you can check it out

Comment: while code "does" the stuff it is improvable for a few reasons: setInterval's callback is called even though not needed anymore(when no update needed), fetching the element at every time is unnecessary (imagine there are 1k stuff on the map you may do 1k getElementById every "time"), you could think of encapsulating as an object (limitAmount, el) such that you can just instantiate those without repeating code (and also slight typo, you use setInterval but pretend using setTimeout!)

Comment: @user753642 Take a look at my answer now :)

Comment: I don't think the caps is on user. It is rather on the mine itself

Comment: @user753642 Maybe. I thought it was the user's total cap, but that's down to OP to implement  :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Kobe's approach may be to create some fire&forget objects.

Consider the class MetalMine

```
class MetalMine {
  constructor () {
    this.amount = 100
    this.timer = setInterval(this.frame.bind(this), this.framePeriod)
  }
  frame () {
    this.amount = Math.min(this.amount + this.frameQuantity, this.maxQuantity)
    if (this.amount === this.maxQuantity) {
      clearInterval(this.timer)
    }
  }
  framePeriod = 3000
  frameQuantity = 10
  maxQuantity = 500
}
```

you could instantiate some mines and forget about them.

```
let mine1 = new MetalMine()
let mine2 = new MetalMine()
let mine3 = new MetalMine()
```

Possibly you may give each of them a dom node, and mine1, ..., mine3 would fill the dom node's html itself.

```
class MetalMine{
  constructor (el) {
    this.$el = el
    ...
  }
  frame () {
    this.amount = ...
    this.$el.textContent = this.amount
    ...
  }
  ...
}
let mine1 = new MetalMine(document.querySelector('#somemine'))
let mine2 = new MetalMine(document.querySelector('#somemine1'))
let mine3 = new MetalMine(document.querySelector('#somemine2'))
```

Or you could go a bit more funky and extend some dom node:

```js
class MetalMine extends HTMLElement{
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
    this.span = document.createElement('span')

    this.amount = 100
    this.timer = setInterval(this.frame.bind(this), this.framePeriod)

    this.frame()
    this.shadowRoot.append(this.span)
  }
  frame () {
    // check yourself that frame is not called anymore once clearInterval
    // has been called
    console.log('called')
    this.amount = Math.min(this.amount + this.frameQuantity, this.maxQuantity)
    this.span.textContent = `metal ${this.amount}`
    if (this.amount === this.maxQuantity) {
      clearInterval(this.timer)
    }
  }
  //set the constants to the prototype
  framePeriod = 3000
  frameQuantity = 10
  maxQuantity = 130
}
customElements.define('my-metalmine', MetalMine)

//create some mine with delay
let body = document.querySelector('body')
body.append(document.createElement('my-metalmine'))
setTimeout( _ => {
  body.append(document.createElement('my-metalmine'))  
  setTimeout(_ => {
    body.append(document.createElement('my-metalmine'))
  }, 1000)
}, 1000)
```

```html
<body></body>
```